# what does PATH/TO/MY_APP means?

Tags: path

Here a step of installation in heroku web hosting website:

1. Track your application with Git

If you’re already using Git with your application, skip to the next step. If you’re not yet using Git to track your application, run this:

```
$ cd PATH/TO/MY_APP
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in .git/
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "new app"
Created initial commit 5df2d09: new app
44 files changed, 8393 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

when I cd to the PATH/TO/MY_APP 
there's no such dictionary, So I guess it's a custom path which should add to the user path file manually, Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means path to your app, so if your app is in /usr/bin/myapp, than it is "/usr/bin/myapp".

Comment: I know it's a rookie question,Thank you Ency