# What is "/path/to"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been doing web programming for some time now, and don't consider myself so much of a total newbie but I still don't understand what "/path/to" is. People use that code a lot, and I used to think it's just a way to refer to main path. But I started wondering why so many people use that syntax so uniformly, because it's confusing if it's meant to be NOT taken literally. Most people would actually type in "/path/to".

So I tried searching for "/path/to" on google, but this is something that's hard to search on a generic search engine, so no luck. So I decided to ask here. Is "/path/to" some kind of jargon that people use to refer to something? If yes, what does it exactly refer to? If no, then how does it work internally?

Comment: That's just a placeholder for an actual path in your environment.

Comment: How would *you* indicate a placeholder for an absolute path in an example?

Comment: I would say "{Your environment path}" or something that clearly lets readers know that it's not a real code. As I mentioned, I've been confused about this since this is a jargon and there is no official document that explains this notation., and it *is* a code, so it's not unnatural for beginners to just take this literally. Let me ask, how did you first learn about this notation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does PATH/TO/MY\_APP means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050440/what-does-path-to-my-app-means)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a placeholder for an actual path in your environment. I usually use it when I want to abstract from the path I use on my machine. It does not matter and the reader/user of my code will likely have it different. So I prefer to clearly indicate what places they should amend.

Other examples of this sort:

```
GET http://example.com
ssh username@host
```

Comment: Hmm. then why do so many people use this notation? Is this like how people use the CONTROLLER#ACTION to refer to controller actions? Do you know why people started using this? I was confused because I couldn't find this in any official document but so many people are using it. At first I actually typed in "/path/to" and was really confused..

Comment: It's a convenient notation. `/path/to/project`. What's so confusing about it? :)

Comment: @Vlad For local files, this notation is used because on my machine it might be `/home/code-apprentice/src/my-cool-ruby-project`, but on your machine it might be `C:\Users\Vlad\Projects\MyEvenBetterRubyProject`. `/path/to/project` just abstracts these details away with a clear description of what the path is to.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is the placeholder only for absolute paths or can we use it for relative paths also?

Comment: @adosar since it's not an actual existing path and is subject to interpretation, you can do whatever you want. But make sure that readers understand that it's supposed to be a relative path. `relative/path/to/asset` or something

Answer (score 2):

`/path/to/project` and similar constructs are used in documentation and blog posts to abstract away details that vary on different machines and for different people. For example, I might be working on a project on my Linux machine that is at `/home/code-apprentice/src/my-cool-ruby-project`. At the same time, you are working on a project on your Windows machine that you put at `C:\Users\Vlad\Projects\MyEvenBetterRubyProject`. We both are reading the same blog article to implement a feature. The detail of the exact path where we each store our project doesn't matter for the particular part of Ruby on Rails that we are using. The notation `/path/to/project` is just a convenient and concise placeholder to describe the root of the project that varies between our machines.