# What's the /path/to means

Tags: ubuntu, caffe

I am a beginner in caffe. In some tutorials I usually see the "/path/to". I'm confuse with that. What's it means. Is that a specific path in my computer?

Here is part of [a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31431716/1714410).

> Prepare your data
>
> Images: put all images in a folder (I'll call it here
>   /path/to/jpegs/). Labels: create a text file (e.g.,
>   /path/to/labels/train.txt) with a line per input image .

Comment: Are you familiar with `C:\outer_folder\inner_folder\ ` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does PATH/TO/MY\_APP means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050440/what-does-path-to-my-app-means)

Answer (score 2):

It's just telling you that you should specify a path, and giving an example of the path format.

```
/path/to/labels/train.txt
```

The tutorial or instructions expect you to replace it with your own path, which can be anything you want **as long as it's in path format**

```
/hanbing/data/train.txt

/documents/cafe/example_app/train.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The `/path/to/labels/train.txt` simply means the `path to where you actually stored` the `train.txt` in your computer.

Say it was kept in a `folder` called `train` in your computer situated in the document folder`(assuming your are using linux)` then the path to the file would be

> `/home/udoyen/Documents/train/train.txt`.

Note:`udoyen` here being my own or yours in which it would have been like this

> `/home/hanbing/Documents/train/train.txt`